# one column with not equal condition in Ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have 5 words in a column where I need to eliminate two words and show the  remaining result
Table name  temp

```
 Id      approval_trade
  1        closed 
  2        closed by
  3        open
  4        target
  5        running
  6        now
```

I need result as  given below using not equal to condition

```
Id      approval_trade
  3        open
  4        target
  5        running
  6        now
```

My query

```
select * 
from temp
where approval_trade <> 'closed' and approval_trade <> 'closed by'
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: Do you simply not get the desired results or does an error occur?  Based on what I"m seeing all I can think of is approval_trade column has "non-display" characters in it such as tab, space or enter which could be why they don't match.

Comment: I did not get the exact result with my query...can I use OR condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have hidden characters that you cannot see but interfere with the comparison.  To start, such a query would normally be written using `NOT IN`:

```
select * 
from temp
where approval_trade not in ('closed', 'closed by');
```

This is shorter and less prone to accidental error.

In your case, I would ask if this returns the rows you don't want:

```
select * 
from temp
where approval_trade in ('closed', 'closed by');
```

If it does, then your query (and the `not in`) version should work.  My guess is that they do not.  Next, I would go for like.  Does this return only the rows you do not want?

```
select * 
from temp
where approval_trade like 'closed*';
```

If this returns exactly what you want out, then use `not like` to get what you want:

```
where approval_trade not like 'closed*'
```

If this doesn't work, then the problem gets harder.  More understanding of what your data exactly looks like and what the queries return would help.